# is my code victim of same origin policy?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, same-origin-policy

Here is my code. You have to kindly look does it suffer from 'same origin policy' in this shape. The domain for HTML is (http://127.0.0.1/jqload.html) & php file (http://127.0.0.1/conn_sql.php). This is json format :  [{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_int"},{"options":"blahblah"}]
  I actually want to append json data that I receive in HTYML with user input & I am suffering in that. If I use eval for parsing, it works fine to point its put here. But if I use JSON.parse to parse, the whole code stops working & this error message is issued '"IMPORTANT: Remove this line from json2.js before deployment". I put my code for some other question on stackoverflow forum & I was told that my code suffer from 'same origin policy' that causes the problems in appending JSON data. So can you kindly see does my code suffer from this policy? Though I have doubts it suffers from that policy as I learn that it restricts if files reside on different domains, here both files reside next to each other.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head></head>
 <body> 
  <form name="index">
   <p><input type = "text" id = "txt" name = "txt"></input>
   <p><input type = "button" id = "send" name = "send" value = "send" onClick= 
       "ADDLISTITEM"></input>
   <p><select name="user_spec" id="user_spec" />
  </form>
  <script>
  function ADDLISTITEM()
  {
      alert (json.length); // working
      alert json.options[1]; // do not show any value, message just for testing
      json.options[json.length+1] = 'newOption'; //not working; HELP HERE
      jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);//working fine for current data
      alert(jsonString);
      //here I have to implement send this stringify(json) back to server,HELP  
      //HERE     
  }                    
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var json;
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      jQuery .getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
          json = jsonData;
          $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
              document.index.user_spec.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Needs a better formatting, and maybe better wording. I still don't know exactly what you are trying to do, nor what is wrong. And I don't know what is "this forum" (is it StackOverflow?).

Comment: Actually originally I want to append json data that I receive from php file in my HTML form with user input. I put my code for some other question on stackoverflow forum & I was told that my code suffer from 'same origin policy' that causes the problems in nappending json data . So can u kindly see does my code suffer from this policy. If so, how could I recover from that policy problem. Though I have doubts that my code suffers from that policy as my both files reside on same domain.

Comment: What errors do you get? Do you see any messages in your console (Ctr-J)? Are you sure the JSON string you get contains valid JSON (according to http://www.jsonlint.com/)? And next time, please don't use 'abbreviations' like "u", just use "you". Also, you should edit your original question rather than opening a new one. But leave it for now, it was quite cumbersome to reformat your question and indent your code. For the record, duplicate of [why JavaScript is not displaying parsed json data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032553/why-javascript-is-not-displaying-parsed-json-data)

Comment: If I use eval() to parse then the code that is now written in this thread is working. But if I use alert json.option[0] i.e. to see if I could append it, it output nothing. & if I use JSON.parse for parsing then 1st of all the original code stops working i.e. populating select with json and it raises error "IMPORTANT: Remove this line from json2.js before deployment". Yes, I check using jsonlint.com & its valid. Sorry, actually I use to save space. Actually I reference that message too in OP, I was not sure that could I change the message title too.

Comment: That message ("Remove this line from json2.js…") is clear in itself: remove that line before you use json2.js. You aren't hotlinking that library, are you?

Comment: But which line to remove? & you asked about console error (ctrl+shift+J), now with this alert message raised, firebug shows no error, though number of warnings. & what you see, is this code violating same origin policy? Seem some people confuse, I clear here my problem lies in ADDLISTITEM script, & after I parse json data to javascript object in main HTML code to use it in this script to append data.

Comment: I am not better aware of term hot linking, if you mean only putting web reference of the library in stead of saving it locally & then referencing its physical location. Then NO, I am using web reference of the library, not storing physically. That is what you can see from my code here

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem you get (and that practice is indeed called 'hotlinking' and is considered a bad practice, because you actually use bandwidth of someone else to facilitate your site; it's only allowed when explicitly mentioned, e.g., when using a Content Delivery Network). When you look at the source of http://www.json.org/json2.js, the first line should be removed after you copy the file to your own server. That way, the annoying alert will vanish.

Comment: OK, thanX a Lot 4 all these information. I was not aware of this. But does that mean I also have to remove the                        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> because it is also used in same way? I used it this way because the examples/tutorial I found from internet were either using this way OR were mentioning to reference this way if you don't want to store it locally. Don't you see any other problem in my code I mean including 'same origin policy'? I am sick now, will test my program making this way tomorrow.

Comment: No, jQuery is hosted on a Content Delivery Network (CDN), which explicitly allows you to use their server to include jQuery. I can't see any other problem in the code you posted, but, as Frode already told you, you don't need to parse the received data when using [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/): “The callback is passed the returned data, which will be a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method.”

Comment: OH OK, yes, its working this was. I can access the json in ADDLISITEM() in javascript format & print its length & agian convert it to JSON format. But why I am not able to print value of individual elements in javascript object by statement json.options[1]?? Now afterward in ADDLISITEM() script, I need to (1)append this javascript object with new value that I get from user,(2)convert it back to JSON format & (3)send it back to server to update data. (2)JSON conversion is working fine for current data, 1st & 3rd steps are still to be implemented.

Comment: the firebug error console showing this error & highlight the 1st line of code i.e. the doctype declaration when I try to print individual item by pressing button, code is edited & you can see how I try to print it by alert.                               Error: ADDLISITEM is not defined
Source File: http://127.0.0.1/jqload.html
Line: 1

Comment: You have an array of objects, not the other way around, so you should access the second (!) item in the array using `json[1].options`. For uploading, you'll have to append the JSON-formatted string to a hidden field of the form before it gets submitted, or send it using an XMLHttpRequest. But please ask these things in new questions, because this is becoming a mess.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, can u kindly see my new question. since no one seems to be interested in it:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You're on the right track, but here: `$.each(jsonData, function (i, j) { ... }` you are actually looping through each character of the `jsonData` string, and not the `json` object. Just change jsonData to json inside the `$.each()`, and it should work fine (regardless of whether you're using eval or JSON.parse, but I recommend the latter).</strike>

Edited: Since you are using `jQuery.getJSON()`, you don't need to use `eval` or `JSON.parse` - jQuery does it for you. So inside your callback function, just set `json = jsonData` .

```
<script>
  var json;
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      jQuery .getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
        json = jsonData;
        $.each(json, function (i, j) {
            document.index.user_spec.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanX to both of u. & sorry that my poor words confuse u Frode. Actually this part is not my problem, its working fine. I declare/ use Global var json here just be able to use it in ADDLISITEM script after parsing it here. And I am parsing json to javascript here that(i.e. js) I need to use in ADDLISTITEMS script I reword my original post. kindly see it. I have actual problems in appending the json data that I receive from php i.e. 'jsonData' with user input